# Which router bit was used on this 18mm plywood drawer front?

Tags: routers

I have 18mm birch ply fronts for my kitchen and I'm trying to identify the correct router bit to use for making recessed drawer pulls. The ones I've been able to find all seem to be for much thicker wood.

This picture is from a company that use 18mm plywood for their drawers. It feels a little cheeky to ask them what bit they use though. Can anyone help me track down the correct bit?

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what I'm looking at here.  Can you post several photos so we can get our bearings?

Comment: OP didn't take this photo. It's in product literature. If you look at the lower right end you can see the bit profile fairly plainly.

Comment: Chances are good it's proprietary. Manufacturers often create and maintain their own tooling. It may also be a combination cut.

Comment: When you say combination cut, do you mean cutting out the front rectangle with a straight bit and then using a cove cutter like this? https://www.trenddirectuk.com/46-270x1-2tc

Comment: Well, the opposite of that. :) That bit matches the remaining wood profile, so you need the inverse. There's also a tight radius curve in the center of the panel's thickness. I'm not a cabinet maker, so I can't offer better insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That big looks close to the thing you are looking for:

[image]

(from [Wallmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Magnate-7401-Drawer-Finger-Pull-Router-Bits-mdash-1-3-8-Overall-Diameter-5-8-Cutting-Length-1-2-Shank-Diameter-3-4-Small-Diameter-2-Shank-Length/55631832))

If you google for "drawer pull cutter" there are many more options.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but it looks like a cove bit.

[image]

Comment: That's part of it, but the curve seems to go beyond 90 degrees, and there's a roundover component as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I have seen is UK only from Wealden Tool.
[https://www.wealdentool.com/cgi-bin/sh000001.pl?WD=scribe%20ovolo&PN=Ovolo-Scribe.html#aT1588B_2d8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT5d1.png)

[image]

[image]